# How to power a remote control car using solar power

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

My daughter is trying to power a remote control car that currently uses 4 AA batteries as power. She is trying to convert it to solar. What does she need to do so?

Comment: Realize that solar powered vehicles, especially those that are directly powered rather than charging batteries, require extreme efficiency.  An ordinary toy will not be convertible, since the motors will require more power than available cells can convert from the light incident on even an oversize chassis area, even in full sun conditions.  A workable design would be built from the ground up with efficiency as a goal.

Comment: Adding to what @ChrisStratton has said, it is possible, but the amount of instantaneous power required by the motors would require a fairly large solar panel, which would actually cause the motors to require more power due to the weight of said panel. This same dilemma is a common back and forth between motor and battery size in mobile robotics. It is possible to use a small solar panel to charge batteries on the car, but it would not run very fast or for very long.

Comment: As a follow up, here is a solar panel at Sparkfun that is rated for 4.5V @ 100mA (0.45W) that 'could' work if there was no internal circuitry that needs regulated power (such as the RC receiver...) and the drive motor(s) draw VERY little current under load. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7845 4 AA batteries is about 6V (4.8 for rechargeable cells) so the motor(s) would be under driven even in full sunlight, and this is not even considering the actual power reduction you will see in the solar panel under such a load.

Answer (score 1):

Solar cars are *really* hard because solar panels are so inefficient.

The energy in sunlight varies greatly by latitude, weather, and time of day. On a clear day, at solar noon, at equitorial latitudes, solar power at Earth's surface can be a little over \$1000\:\mathrm{W/m}^2\$. However, it's much lower at other times of the day and latitudes. For a lower bound, the WMO defines [direct sunlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight) as anything above \$120\:\mathrm{W/m}^2\$. Clouds and smog of course can mean even less.

Additionally, we don't have any really efficient converters of sunlight to electrical energy. Even the [most efficient seem to be about 35%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photovoltaics), with the types that aren't research projects or only available to NASA coming in around 15% efficient, according to some quick research I just did.

So let's assume this car is big enough to support a panel the size of an A4 sheet of paper. That's \$210\:\mathrm{mm}\cdot 297\:\mathrm{mm} \approx 0.06\:\mathrm m^2 \$ of area available to collect light. How much energy is available? In the worst case:

$$ 0.06\:\mathrm m^2 \cdot 120 \:\mathrm{W/m}^2 \cdot 0.15 \approx 1W $$

In the best case:

$$ 0.06\:\mathrm m^2 \cdot 1000 \:\mathrm{W/m}^2 \cdot 0.15 \approx 60W $$

What can we do with about one watt? Maybe it's best to compare to the battery in the car. It looks like the 7.2V battery packs used in many RC cars has a capacity of \$3000\:\mathrm{mAh}\$ (three amp-hours). We can get a very rough idea of the total energy in that pack by multiplying the voltage by the capacity:

$$ 7.2\:\mathrm V \cdot 3\:\mathrm{Ah} \cdot {3600\:\mathrm s \over 1\:\mathrm h} = 77760\:\mathrm J $$

A watt is one joule per second. So, the rate of energy available from the solar panel is about the same as if you drained that battery constantly over a period of 77760 seconds or 21 hours. How slowly would you have to drive that car to make the batteries last 21 hours? That's how fast it can go with the rate of energy available from the solar panel.

Using the best case of 60 watts is somewhat more favorable, but it's a fair guess you will want the car to work in less than optimum conditions. In practice of course you will get something in between.

With some very careful engineering you can get something that works, but it's never going to zip around like a battery-powered car can. It helps a lot to point the panels directly at the sun, but to keep them pointed at the sun as the car drives would require a very complex mechanism. Additionally you'd probably want to go through every part of the car and make it as efficient as possible. Minimize rolling resistance on the tires. Minimize any transmission losses. Use a very efficient motor. Make the car as light as possible, etc.

These are rough calculations, of course, but serve to demonstrate the point: solar cars are *hard*. If they were easy, everyone would be driving them.

Comment: wait a second, you quote 120 W / m2 as the available resource, that's not right, from the link you provided: *"but the total amount (direct and indirect from the atmosphere) hitting the ground is around 1120 W/m2.[3] In terms of energy, sunlight at the earth's surface is around 52 to 55 percent infrared (above 700 nm), 43 to 42 percent visible (400 to 700 nm), and 5 to 3 percent ultraviolet (below 400 nm)."* so you end up with ~10W so you would need to drive the car slow enough to keep the battery going for 2.1 hours. Don't you agree?

Comment: @evan54, it varies a lot on weather. Numbers in the ballpark of one kilowatt per square meter assume the sun is at its zenith, and the sky is clear. Those conditions only exist at noon at equatorial latitudes in good weather. If we want something that will work in the temperate areas where a lot of people live, at times of day other than noon, and also on less than clear days, we have much less power available. Research [insolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insolation) for more specific data on how much is available in particular areas. It's always less than the maximum of 1120W/m^2.

Comment: I agree that 1120 is closer to the max but working on the assumption of 120W/m2 I think is definitely on the low end, and in the end of the day if you're making a toy, you can make a toy that runs well at noon and not well the rest of the day, I'd still consider that a success and a working toy. You're never going to design a solar toy that works at nighttime (well you could but it just becomes an RC car with a battery and a load), similarly I would think it reasonable to limit yourself to times near noon.

Comment: also here is an example, sure it may be a bit larger than A4 but definitely possible!

Comment: @evan54 Sure it's on the low end. It's the minimum threshold the WMO uses to define "sunshine". We can argue about the threshold all you want. If you want to engineer for some other threshold, just do the math with another number.

Comment: yes, it's on the low end, and you make it sound like it's an impossible feat and base it on that number, hence the criticism. I'd hate to see people put off from trying this task because they read that number in your answer!

Comment: @evan54 It is pretty impossible. That's why solar cars aren't commercially available. I've elaborated the answer a bit. If you still disagree, feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: appreciate the additions, also, yes solar cars aren't commercially available and I agree never will be, this question is about **RC cars**. here is one that works http://www.instructables.com/id/Building-a-Solar-Powered-RC-car/. I would write my own answer but I can't the question is protected " protected by Kortuk♦ Apr 30 '13 at 2:39

Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site. " :(